# Phing override property in child task

Tags: php, phing

I am trying to split a complex phing based process into smaller steps, however I hit the issue with access to properties in subsequent tasks. Basically, what I am trying to achive is to define few properties in mater build file, like `${repositoryUrl}`, or `${clientName}` and adjust, or even define new properties, in subsequent targets (say export from repository, then removing a few files, then migrating database, then deplying to the server). 
I have tried **PhingTask**, **PhingImportTask** and **PhingCall**, all of which seem to have an own, local scope for the properties. So, the bottom line is: is it even possible to *(re) define* properties in Phing in files different than first one, passed to phing as paramaeter (build.xml by default)?

Answer (score 2):

So, I found the answer myself, and I think it's worth sharing:
In order to inherit properties in following task you have to split your build into multiple phases, and have one master file (say `build.xml`) which sole purpose is to launch all tasks, like so:

```
    <target name="buildAll" description="runs build steps, preserves the environment" 
    depends = 
    "prepare, 
    filter, 
    config, 
    migrate, 
    backup, 
    deploy">
```

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the previous answer, I made a test with Phing Targets, called with

< phingcall >

Setting a Property, which is defined in the main,default target,
in a Sub-Target, does not influence the Property in the Main Target or 
in another Sub-Target.

Whereas it is possible, to change the property in the main target,
and work with that property in the other Sub-Targets.

With this behaviour it is hard to work straight with the targets. :-(